# Upload photos on my website in real time with twitter, instagram or another service

Tags: api, twitter, instagram, image-uploading

I have a question about uploading images from my smartphone to my website.
I want create a little blog where I write and upload image in real time.
For example I like this restaurant, i take pictures of dishes and I share those pic on my blog.

My question is: is possible using the Api/App of twitter or instagram do that?
Take a picture from my smartphone camera, have a "button" for share image on my website.

I hope my english let you understand what I say.

thank's Davide

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes - you can publish your photo on for example twitter and then use one of many  ways to show this (your twitter feed as an example) on your blog. The easiest will probably be to use a twitter widget: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

Of course, you can also use the APIs to import the photos from twitter/insta - but that requires more coding,